# jQuery cannot select form input nested within table

Tags: html, forms, html-table, jquery-selectors

I have an html form with an input element. Every time I put that form inside table tag 
`<table><form></form></table>`, jQuery selector cannot select the input that's inside the form.

This is the code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myForm #textinput1").val("hahaha");
  });   
</script>
<table>
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
<input type="text" name="textinput1" id="textinput1" />
</form>
</table>
```

But the following works :

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
<table><input type="text" name="textinput1" id="textinput1" /></table>
</form>
```

And the following works too :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#textinput1").val("hahaha");
    }); 
</script>
<table>
    <form name="myForm" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="textinput1" id="textinput1" />
    </form>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, A `table` cannot contain a `form` directly.

You can nest the table within the form.

```
<form>
  <table>
    <tr> <td> My Content </td> </tr>
  <table>
</form>
```

Or

```
<table>
    <tr> 
       <td> 
          <form>My Content </form>
       </td> 
    </tr>
 <table>
```

Comment: finally i found the problem... not only that you mention above, but when i put <form> and </form> in different col (<td>) or inside the <tr> but outside the <td> element. that doesn't work too... thanks so much robin maben...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  document.getElementById("textinput1").value;
```

Comment: i think that's same with "$("#textinput1").val();" but what i want to know is why when i put myForm inside table element, i cannot select using jquery selector?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#textinput1").val("hahaha");
});
```

```
<table>
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
<input type="text" name="textinput1" id="textinput1" />
</form>
```

in the above code your are selecting input element directly with its id. if you try to select like

```
$("form#myform #textinput1").val("hahaha");
```

you can't. untill you have the form inside your table.